# Discarding non-decimal values in R

Tags: r

I've got the a data frame called "odds" in R containing a couple of odds I kept track of in several formats:

```
timestamp   RX  R1  R2
2013-04-13 00:26:49 3.65    1.50    7.00
2013-04-13 00:26:49 3.70    1.50    8.00
2013-04-13 00:26:49 +375    -250    +860
2013-04-13 00:35:01 3.65    1.50    7.00
2013-04-13 00:35:01 3.70    1.50    8.00
2013-04-13 00:35:01 3.70    1.45    7.00
2013-04-13 00:36:55 +320    -250    +600
2013-04-13 01:00:01 3.65    1.50    7.00
2013-04-13 00:36:55 3.70    1.50    8.00
2013-04-13 00:36:55 3.70    1.45    7.00
```

How can discard the rows not in decimal format?

In the example I just gave, the third and the seventh rows should have been deleted entirely.

Cheers

Comment: `dat[ grep(".", dat$R1, fixed=TRUE, invert=TRUE), ]` or something to that effect?

Comment: `keepers <- RX == as.integer(RX); your.data.frame[keepers,]`

Comment: @CauchyDistributedRV: no idea; I've just updated the question.

Comment: @Justin: nop. <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Assuming myDF is your data.frame
myDF[abs(as.numeric(myDF$RX)) < 100, ]

             timestamp   RX   R1 R2
1  2013-04-13 00:26:49 3.65 1.50  7
2  2013-04-13 00:26:49 3.70 1.50  8
4  2013-04-13 00:35:01 3.65 1.50  7    <~~~  Third Row is gone
5  2013-04-13 00:35:01 3.70 1.50  8
6  2013-04-13 00:35:01 3.70 1.45  7
8  2013-04-13 01:00:01 3.65 1.50  7    <~~~  So is the 7th Row
9  2013-04-13 00:36:55 3.70 1.50  8
10 2013-04-13 00:36:55 3.70 1.45  7
```

Note:  If `RX` is a factor, then you need to use  `as.numeric(as.character(RX))` instead of just `as.numeric(RX)`

---

#### Edit as per concern in the comments:

The above example is based on copying+pasting the OP sample data.
If the process is not working for you, then that indicates that there is a difference between your real data and the sample data.

Take a look at the differences and that will help lead you in the right direction.

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I want, but I can't say it's working... I do have an extra column containing bookies (eg: "bwin", "William Hill", etc) called 'bookie' after the R2 column (which I omitted for simplification). Does it make a difference ?

Comment: After running myDF <- odds[c(1,2,3)] I can confirm it did not work.

Comment: is `RX` a factor?   if so,  you need to use  `as.numeric(as.character(RX))` instead of just `as.numeric(RX)`

Comment: Not really sure; i'll check it once I get home though. The data was imported from a CSV file using RStudio's GUI. Is there a command i can run to find out ?

Comment: just try `is.factor(myDF$RX)` (regardless of how it was imported)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is indeed factor and your answer works perfectly. Cheers